# How export a specific query in mongo to csv?

Tags: mongodb, csv, robo3t

I'm am searching for either on how to export a query result from mongo to CVS or excel, or how to export results in robomongo. I found mongoexport but I think that only can export a collection with some simple constraints.

This is my query:

```
 db.getCollection('user').find({ "coins": { $elemMatch: { "id":"30","amount":0} }  })
```

Answer (score 11):

For MongoDB 3.0+, you can specify the query into *mongoexport* using *-q* and *--type* options:

```
mongoexport -d test -c user -q '{ coins: { $elemMatch: { "id":"30","amount":0}}}' --type=csv --out exportdir/myRecords.json
```

For earlier versions, use --csv option with the header fields:

```
mongoexport -d test -c user -q '{ coins: { $elemMatch: { "id":"30","amount":0}}}' --csv -f first_name,last_name,title --out exportdir/myRecords.json
```

Comment: can't use mongoexport in this case because data es deep, for example column color have red,blue,yellow .. end others are similars. mongoexport undestand that is for simple rows (one color, not arrays).

Answer (score 9):

You can use forEach to look through each result and a function to format them.  Something like:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({ "coins": { $elemMatch: { "id":"30","amount":0} }  })
.forEach(function(u){

  print('"' + u._id + '","' + u.amount + '"');

});
```

Then just send the output to a file.

Comment: Ben, how do I "just send the output to a file"?

Comment: @PostureOfLearning save your script as js file script.js `mongo test script.js > out.csv`